# Lost my path after upgrading to Lion GM? How do I fix this?

Tags: xcode, path

I just upgraded to the GM version of Lion. I've been using the previews without a problem, but something happened with the latest install and I lost my "path", so now I can't compile anything with gcc or g++. I finally found gcc and g++ in /Developer/usr/bin, but now it can't find the include directories.

Is there a simple way to fix all my paths so my tools will work again? Or is reinstalling Xcode the easiest way to fix that?

I say "path" because I don't know all the different places path information is stored on OS X.

Comment: Installing the new version of xcode fixed this.

Comment: Possibly unrelated but I lost some PSQL settings when I went to Yosemite and so I effectively lost months of data.  I shall not be upgrading again until this project is long over!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling xcode fixed everything.